# jQuery add a Class on hover - object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a Class to an img when the mouse is over an element and remove the class when the mouse is no longer over the element. I'm using object literal notation. I can't see to select the correct image, can anyone see where i'm going wrong?

```js
let Cc = {
    bindEvent: function() {
        $('.title.em-below').hover( function() {
            let selectedtitle = $(this);
            Cc.scaleThumbnail(selectedtitle);
        })
    },
    scaleThumbnail: function(selectedtitle) {
        let $thumbnail = selectedtitle.siblings('.image-thumbnail')
        let img = $thumbnail.children('img');
        console.log(img);
        img.addClass('thumbnail-active');
        img.removeClass('thumbnail-active');
    },
}
```

```css
.thumbnail-active {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title em-below">
        Title
    </div>
    <a class="image-thumbnail">
        <div class="wide-thumbnail em-below">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>
        </div>
    </a>                  
</div>
```

Comment: You're never calling the functions.

Comment: `hover()` needs two arguments: a function when the mouse goes in, and a function to undo it when the mouse leaves.

Comment: @Barmar actually first gets called for both events when only one provided. But do need a way to undo for sure

Comment: @charlietfl But he wants to do different things: add a class when hovering, remove the class when leaving.

Comment: But maybe the same function can be used if it uses `toggleClass()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `CC.bindEvent()` to bind the event handler. And your hover function needs to toggle the class, not add it and then immediately remove it.

The `img` element is not a child of `$thumbnail`, it's the grandchild. Use `.find()` instead of `.children()`.

```js
let Cc = {
    bindEvent: function() {
        $('.title.em-below').hover( function() {
            let selectedtitle = $(this);
            Cc.scaleThumbnail(selectedtitle);
        })
    },
    scaleThumbnail: function(selectedtitle) {
        let $thumbnail = selectedtitle.siblings('.image-thumbnail')
        let img = $thumbnail.find('img');
        //console.log(img.attr('src'));
        img.toggleClass('thumbnail-active');
    },
}


Cc.bindEvent();
```

```css
.thumbnail-active {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title em-below">
        Title
    </div>
    <a class="image-thumbnail">
        <div class="wide-thumbnail em-below">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>
        </div>
    </a>                  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for taking the time to help it's so clear now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line, because of which the `img` tag is not captured.

`$thumbnail.children('img');`

`.children` only traverses its immediate child which is `.wide-thumbnail.em-below`.

Use `.find` instead

`$thumbnail.find('img');`

Comment: only part of the issue when OP adds and then immediately removes the same class

Comment: I appreciate the help @Sushanth, you're explanation was very clear.